# Is $\mathbb{R}^n$ a polyhedron?

Tags: geometry

A polyhedron is defined as the intersection of a finite collection of generalized halfspaces. In my book, a generalized halfspace is defined as a set where we allow the vector of coefficients $(a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_n )$ in the definition of a halfspace to vanish (or = 0).

I said yes. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a polyhedron because a generalized halfspace can be all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. But I feel there's something wrong with that logic. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is not a polyhedron. You mentioned that a generalized halfspace can be all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but that is not that case. By definition, a halfspace can only emcompass half of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'm not sure what definition you're given for a generalized halfspace, but it's just the direct analogue of the three dimensional case.

Since a polyhedron is by definition the intersection of a finite collection of halfspaces, if $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a polyhedron then there must be at least one halfspace that describes it. However, as noted above, $\mathbb{R}^n$ cannot be described by a single halfspace. Additionally, whenever another halfspace is added to your collection of halfspaces that describe $\mathbb{R}^n$, the number of possible points described cannot increase (that is, at best you retain the same number of points in the intersection). Since a single halfspace does not describe $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the addition of other halfspaces cannot add points to the description of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbb{R}^n$ cannot be described by the intersection of a finite number of halfspaces. Thus, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not a polyhedron.

Comment: Is the empty set not finite?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I'm not sure what you mean. I freely admit that this isn't my area, so what I've written may be incorrect.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're saying, but wouldn't that make all sorts of things fit in the definition of polyhedron that we don't want? I'm still not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: Do you mean to say, "...but that is *not* the case?"

Comment: @RobertIsrael: How do you define the intersection of *no* sets?

Comment: @celtschk Coincidently my lecturer also treats $R^n$ as the intersection of 0 halfspace, which is kinda weird.

Answer (score -1):

Geometry isn't exactly my area of expertise, either. So let's start with the basics: What is the definition of a "generalized half-space"? [Wikipedia's article on half-spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-space_%28geometry%29) gives the following definition:

> In geometry, a half-space is either of the two parts into which a plane divides the three-dimensional Euclidean space. More generally, a half-space is either of the two parts into which a hyperplane divides an affine space.

From this definition, I would say that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not a generalized halfspace itself. Now, can we take the intersection of a finite collection of generalized halfspaces to get $\mathbb{R}^n$? Let's assume that we can do so. Name the collection $\mathbb{H}$. Now consider one of these generalized halfspaces $H \in \mathbb{H}$. Now we must have $\mathbb{R}^n \subseteq H$ because by our assumption $\mathbb{R}^n = \bigcap \mathbb{H}$. However, this is a contradiction.

Comment: Wikipedia only defines ordinary half-spaces. The OP defined generalized half-spaces. It is any set of points $\vec x\in\mathbb R^n$ satisfying $\vec a\cdot\vec x=a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots+a_nx_n\leq b$ , where $\vec a$ is allowed to be $\vec0$. This obviously does include $\mathbb R^n$ itself. Even with ordinary half-spaces, an empty intersection is all of $\mathbb R^n$ (just like the empty product is $1$).