# Is $\mathbb{R}^2$ a polyhedron?

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, polyhedra

I'll appreciate if anyone can explain to me if $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a polyhedron? I saw this link [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151729/is-mathbbrn-a-polyhedron) which says $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not a polyhedron, but could one think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as an intersection of halfspaces in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$? Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of polyhedron?

Comment: Typically a polyhedron will have vertices.

Comment: @Théophile, a intersection of a finite collection of halfspaces

Comment: @CyclotomicField Often, yes, but it really depends on the context or definition. In some contexts, polyhedra are bounded but not necessarily convex; in others, they are convex but not necessarily bounded, etc. The definition might be "points, lines, and faces", or "intersection of half-planes", etc.

Comment: This was already discussed in the linked thread, but the intersection of a *finite* number of half-spaces includes the intersection of *zero* half-spaces, which usually is defined to be the whole space. So it makes sense to even have $\Bbb R^n$ as a polyhedron in $\Bbb R^n$ (an not just $\Bbb R^{n+1}$). In the end it comes down to conventions, but my feeling is that many theorems can be more naturally formulated by allowing the whole space as a polyhedron (e.g. the equivalence between H- and V-representations of polyhedra)

Comment: @M.Winter Indeed, this is a useful inclusion. The next definition question is whether we allow a "polyhedron" to have any number of dimensions, or specifically restrict it to $\Bbb R^3$, using "polytope" for the general case.

Comment: @Théophile It is common (though somehow unfortunate) to define a polyhedron as the intersection of finitely many half-spaces in arbitrary dimension, and a polytope as a bounded polyhedron. The way in which OP stated his question makes me believe that these are the definitions that he is using.

Comment: @M.Winter That is unfortunate. :)

Comment: I have closed this question as a duplicate, as it is not clear how your question is distinct from the question you cite.  How do that *answers* there fail to address your question?  How is your question *distinct* from the linked question?  What definitions are you using (e.g. what is a "polyhedron"?)?

Answer (score 2):

If the ambient space is $\Bbb R^3$, then by your definition, the $x,y$-plane $P$ is a polyhedron, since it is the intersection of two half-spaces:

$$P = \{(x,y,z) : z\ge0\} \cap \{(x,y,z) : z\le0\}$$

Technically, this isn't the same as $\Bbb R^2$, but there is a natural bijection between $P$ and $\Bbb R^2$.

---

Explanation of technicality: $\Bbb R^2$ consists of ordered pairs $(x,y)$. On the other hand, $P$ consists of an ordered triplet $(x,y,0)$. You can map from $P$ to $\Bbb R^2$ in a natural way by defining
$$f(x,y,0) = (x,y),$$
and similar for the reverse direction, so in many respects they "look the same".

Now consider a function like $g(x,y,z) = z$. When restricted to $P$, we have $g(x,y,z) = 0$ everywhere. On the other hand, $g$ cannot be applied to $\Bbb R^2$, since there simply is no $z$-coordinate.

Finally, even if you very informally speak of $\Bbb R^2$ as a plane within $\Bbb R^3$, keep in mind that there's an ambiguity: are you referring to the $x,y$-plane? The $x,z$-plane? A plane on a diagonal? (Case in point: in my answer, I wasn't sure which plane you were referring to, so I arbitrarily used the $x,y$-plane for simplicity.)

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain why it shouldn't "technically" be the same as $\mathbb{R}^2$? How would anyone be able to tell the difference if presented with both without knowing the sources?

Comment: @minuscler Sure: I've written out an explanation.

Comment: thanks for the detail

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{R}^2$ may indeed be constructed as the set of tangent planes and, in general $\mathbb{R}^n$ may be constructed as the set of tangent $\mathbb{R}^(n-1)$ spaces. But these constructions are not polyhedra. The set of subspaces is known as the [tangent bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle).

In the plane, the 1-sphere or circle is an example of a conic section. In 3-space the sphere is an example of a quadric surface. And so on. These can all be constructed as what are known as the [envelopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)) of their tangent bundles.

One may obtain such an envelope as the limit in a series of $n$-sided polyhedra where $n$ tends to infinity, i.e. as an infinite-faced polyhedron or apeirohedron. But the faces degenerate to points, so one may wish to regard the apeirohedron as degenerate and therefore not a valid understanding of the sphere.